# Python json How to add data

Tags: python, json

I don't speak English well
So the question may be a bit odd

```
{
    "arg1": {
        "1": "1",
        "2": "2"
    },
    "arg2": {
        "1": "1",
        "2": "2"
    },
    "arg3": {
        "1": "1",
        "2": "2"
    }
}
```

I want to store data this way. What should I do?

```
json_data = {arg3: {"1": "1", "2": "2"}}
with open(f'./Json/test.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as make_file:
    json.dump(json_data, make_file, ensure_ascii=False ,indent="\t")
```

Is this right?
I would appreciate it if you let me know.

I don't know what to do by deleting the original content.

Comment: Welcome. `indent=4` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine.  The only problem I see when your running it is that that `arg3` needs to be written as `"arg3"` in double quotes (single quotes are invalid in json) unless you have a value for it defined previously.

```py
json_data = {"arg3": {"1": "1", "2": "2"}}
```

Make that change, and you should be able to load and properly display your JSON with:

```py
with open(f'output.json') as f:
    a = json.load(f)
    print(json.dumps(a, indent="\t"))
```

If you do the `json.dumps()` you get a properly formatted json which you can then call `print` on to display.